# Push key always null

Tags: codenameone

I want to use push notification in android but the push key is always null. what might be the reason? I have a professional account which supports push notification. When I debug the app in devices, the pushkey value is always null.

Code:

```
String pushKey = Push.getPushKey();
System.out.println("push " + pushKey );
```

Answer (score 0):

Push key will only return a valid value after `registeredForPush` is invoked. You need to register then when registration succeeds the key will be valid.

If it doesn't you will get an error.

Notice this works on the device. You can simulate this process in the push console in the simulator.